# What OS, hardware, and how to optimize server for high volume traffic

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, performance, database-performance

The framework I am using is called SocialEngine.net v4, and it's completely written in Zend, so it's insanely super CPU intensive. SocialEngine is in PHP and uses MySQL.

I need to know what OS, what hardware you suggest (dual xeons, amd, how much ram, etc...) and how to optimize it properly to handle large amounts of traffic.

I know it can handle large amounts of load, as that is what it was designed for, and I've read about people running social engine with 100k+ users.

I only have 11k users right now, and it's running incredibly slow, I'm talking 7 second page load times.

The framework however does have memcached, and apc options for caching installed, but even with those options on, it doesn't make a big enough difference...

I need to know what the best way to attack this is as far as optimizing mysql, inoodb tweaks, apache tweaks, any performance tweaks, what type of hardware, and amount of ram.

I have a very big marketing plan in place, and will probably start increasing traffic by 1,000+ signups per day... So traffic will start to rise very progressively. When I initially marketed, I did 50k uniques in 6 hours, 20k signups, and 500k pageviews... (server crashed, lost half my users... and haven't marketed since, because I been trying to rebuild)

Sorry for this long explanation, but I really need help, so thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, **analize**!

use `top`, `iostat`, `systat`, and lots of other tools to first determine where's the bottleneck.  is it on the database?  are your cached items expired or invalidated too soon?  are you *positive* they're hitting the cache before the database?  are all the tables well indexed?

many, many more questions like this.  only after answering most of them, start looking at the hardware.

Comment: When running top, the cpu usage spikes to 40% when I just load a new page...

Comment: As far as caching is, I'm really sure how to tell if caching is working properly. I have memcache and APC both installed, and I have tried both, and the speed difference was still horrible.

Comment: what process is piking the CPU? (PHP? MySQL? memcached?)  is it "real CPU", or waiting? (a process stuck on a slow block device still adds to the load average).  have you checked the DB indexes?

Comment: I believe it's really the PHP, because httpd jumps to the top, it shows two process of httpd both around 10 - 20%, it's insane...

Comment: mysqld jumps up a bit, like 2%

Comment: sounds like very bad queries, where you pull all records and filter in PHP.  check the slowqueries log